# How to make left menu height grow according to the content on the right

Tags: html, css

I want the menu on the left to grow according to the content in the right, instead of setting the height of all the sections available.

In this case I would want the menu on the left to finish below the Choice 10 of the content in the right and then the menu would have a scroll (which I have already added in CSS).

Thanks in advance ! :)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i');
* {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .wrapper,
  .disclaimer {
    width: 90vw !important;
  }
}

ol {
  text-align: left;
}

.answered {
  font-weight: 900;
}

.answered::after {
  content: '•';
  color: black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.sections-choices {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid #ddeafa;
  margin: 0 25px 15px 25px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  /* height: 300px;
                min-height: 300px;
                max-height: 350px; */
}

.sections {
  color: gainsboro;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 20%;
  height: inherit;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sections .question-select {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.sections h4 {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
  background-color: #3a3838;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.sections .intro-text {
  padding-top: 2.5px;
  padding-bottom: 2.5px;
}

.sections a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.choices {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  height: inherit;
}

.choices-section-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #3a3838;
}

.choices-section-title h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  color: white;
}

.choices-title {
  padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
  line-height: 19px;
}

.help-text {
  padding: 5px 15px 0 15px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.help-text p {
  margin: 0;
}

.choices-radio {
  padding: 15px 15px 0 25px;
}

.choices-radio label {
  /* word-wrap: break-word; */
  white-space: normal;
}

.choices-radio input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* TOOLTIP */

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: black;
}

.tooltip img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  right: 105%;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* CHANGE RADIO BUTTONS ASPECT */


/* The container */

.radio-style {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default radio button */

.radio-style input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Create a custom radio button */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.radio-style:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */

.radio-style input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: black;
}


/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */

.radio-style input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */

.radio-style .checkmark:after {
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}


/* SCROLLBAR */


/* width */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="margin: 0 auto; max-height: 70vh; background-color: #DCE3EA; text-align: center; margin-top: 15px; font-family: Roboto Condensed, sans-serif;">
  <div class="wrapper" style="padding: 15px 0; width: 70vw; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #a8a8a8;">


    <div class="sections-choices">
      <div class="sections">
        <h4>1. Section 1</h4>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 3</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 4</a></p>

        <h4>2. Section 2</h4>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>

        <h4>3. Section 3</h4>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 3</a></p>

        <h4>4. Section 4</h4>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>

        <h4>5. Section 5</h4>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 3</a></p>

        <h4>6. Section 6</h4>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 3</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 4</a></p>
        <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 5</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="choices">
        <div class="choices-section-title">
          <h4>Section 1 out of 6</h4>
          <h4>Question 1 out of 4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="choices-title"><b>1. This is Question 1 ?</b></div>
        <div class="help-text">
          <div class="tooltip">
            <img src="" width="18px"> More information
            <span class="tooltiptext"> Tooltip text </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="choices-radio">
          <label class="radio-style">Choice 1
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 2
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 3
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 4
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 5
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 6
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 7
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 8
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 9
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>

          <label class="radio-style">Choice 10
                                <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This effect seems default because of the resolution, as the screen height needs to be covered. Have you tried resizing the browser window?? and found the same result?? or did you get scroll

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I resize the window I get the result I want. How do I fix it permanently ?

Comment: But it only happens in resize if I have this -> height: -webkit-fill-available; in class "sections"

Comment: If I dont have that property and resize the window, a scroll is added to the page

Comment: Not overly sure about how to do this with pure css, however with jquery and css you could set the sections class to height:100% and change the height of the container to the same height of the choices class, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmtgeu74/2/

Comment: @fcff94 glad I could help, I've put it down as an answer, please mark it so we can get this question cleared :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not overly sure about how to do this with pure css, however with jquery and css you could set the sections class to height:100% and change the height of the container to the same height of the choices class, something like this:

First, add the height attribute to the .sections element as 100%, this will fill out the container.

```
.sections {
    color: gainsboro;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 20%;
    overflow: scroll;
    height:100%;
}
```

Then with some jquery, you can change the height of its parent to be the same height as the .choices element:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var height = $(".choices").height();

console.log(height);

$(".sections-choices").css("height",height);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

var height = $(".choices").height();

console.log(height);

$(".sections-choices").css("height",height);

});
```

```css
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i');

        * {
            font-family: Roboto, sans-serif !important;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {

            .wrapper,
            .disclaimer {
                width: 90vw !important;
            }
        }
        
        body {
          height:438px;
        }
        
        .wrapper {
          height:438px;
        }

        ol {
            text-align: left;
        }


        .answered {
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        .answered::after {
            content: '•';
            color: black;
            margin-left: 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }



        .sections-choices {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            border: 1px solid #ddeafa;
            margin: 0 25px 15px 25px;
            width: 95%;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            background-color: white;
            /* height: 300px;
            min-height: 300px;
            max-height: 350px; */
            
        }

        .sections {
            color: gainsboro;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 13px;
            background-color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 20%;
            overflow: scroll;
            height:100%;
        }

        .sections .question-select {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .sections h4 {
            padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
            background-color: #3a3838;
            color: white;
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .sections .intro-text {
            padding-top: 2.5px;
            padding-bottom: 2.5px;
        }

        .sections a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        .choices {
            color: black;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: left;
            width: 80%;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            height: inherit;
        }

        .choices-section-title {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            width: auto;
            background-color: #3a3838;
        }

        .choices-section-title h4 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 15px 15px;
            color: white;
        }

        .choices-title {
            padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
            line-height: 19px;
        }

        .help-text {
            padding: 5px 15px 0 15px;
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .help-text p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .choices-radio {
            padding: 15px 15px 0 25px;
        }

        .choices-radio label {
            /* word-wrap: break-word; */
            white-space: normal;
        }

        .choices-radio input {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }


        /* TOOLTIP */

        .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            font-size: 12px;
            display: inline-flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: row;
            color: black;
        }

        .tooltip img {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .tooltip .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            color: black;
            text-align: left;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 10px;
            /* Position the tooltip */
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            top: -5px;
            right: 105%;
        }

        .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
        }


        /* CHANGE RADIO BUTTONS ASPECT */


        /* The container */

        .radio-style {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 25px;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 13px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }


        /* Hide the browser's default radio button */

        .radio-style input {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* Create a custom radio button */

        .checkmark {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 18px;
            width: 18px;
            background-color: gainsboro;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

        .radio-style:hover input~.checkmark {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        /* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */

        .radio-style input:checked~.checkmark {
            background-color: black;
        }

        /* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */

        .checkmark:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
        }

        /* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */

        .radio-style input:checked~.checkmark:after {
            display: block;
        }

        /* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */

        .radio-style .checkmark:after {
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 6px;
            height: 6px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
        }

        /* SCROLLBAR */
        /* width */

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 8px;
        }

        /* Track */

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background: #f1f1f1;
        }

        /* Handle */

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: #888;
        }

        /* Handle on hover */

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: #555;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0 auto; max-height: 70vh; background-color: #DCE3EA; text-align: center; margin-top: 15px; font-family: Roboto Condensed, sans-serif;">
    <div class="wrapper">


        <div class="sections-choices">
            <div class="sections">
                <h4>1. Section 1</h4>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 3</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 4</a></p>

                <h4>2. Section 2</h4>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>

                <h4>3. Section 3</h4>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 3</a></p>

                <h4>4. Section 4</h4>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>

                <h4>5. Section 5</h4>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 3</a></p>

                <h4>6. Section 6</h4>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 1</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 2</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 3</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 4</a></p>
                <p class="question-select"><a href="">Question 5</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="choices">
                <div class="choices-section-title">
                    <h4>Section 1 out of 6</h4>
                    <h4>Question 1 out of 4</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="choices-title"><b>1. This is Question 1 ?</b></div>
                <div class="help-text">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        <img src="" width="18px"> More information
                        <span class="tooltiptext"> Tooltip text </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="choices-radio">
                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 1
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 2
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 3
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 4
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 5
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 6
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 7
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 8
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 9
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-style">Choice 10
                        <input type="radio" value="choice1" name="choice1"><br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```